# Error in rgdal::OSRIsProjected(obj) : Can't parse user input string

Tags: r, rgdal

I have a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame dataset called `election` which includes US County polygons and some attributes. I tried to summary this dataset. But there is an error.

`summary(election)`

> Error in rgdal::OSRIsProjected(obj) : Can't parse user input string
> In addition: Warning message: In wkt(obj) : CRS object has no comment

The same error also occur when I `plot(election)`.
No error generated when I `name(election)` and `head(election)`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, and hopefully you will have found a solution by now, but I ran across the same issue on what I assume is the same dataset/shapefile, so I'm adding this in case anyone comes across the same problem.

Getting the error:

```
Error in rgdal::OSRIsProjected(obj) : Can't parse user input string
In addition: Warning message:
In wkt(obj) : CRS object has no comment
```

usually means that the CRS (proj4string for sp objects), or some other aspect of the spdf is invalid. In this case, it actually seems to just be a simple typo; there's just a missing space.

The proj4string, `+proj=lcc+lon_0=90w +lat_1=20n +lat_2=60n`

should be,      `+proj=lcc +lon_0=90w +lat_1=20n +lat_2=60n`

Note the missing space between "lcc" and "+lon_0=90w"!

However, using `proj4string(x)<-` fails, again because the p4s is invalid, but we can set the argument manually with

```
election@proj4string@projargs <- "+proj=lcc +lon_0=90w +lat_1=20n +lat_2=60n"
```

Hope this helps anyone who seems to have this issue! I've noticed all the issues come from presumably the same dataset.

Best,